# Can't generate en_US.UTF-8 Locale

Tags: debian, locale

I've been trying to set my locale to `en_US.UTF-8` without any success. Based off of other answers around the internet, I should first generate the locale with

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

And then apply it with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

However, running `locale-gen` does something weird:

```
user@Host /home/user $ sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
Generation complete.
```

As you see, it never actually generates UTF-8, but instead keeps falling back to ISO-8859-1. I can never manage to set `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF-8`, probably because it can't generate.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm running Debian 8.1.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You've tried to apply a recipe for Ubuntu under Debian. That usually works, but in this specific case it doesn't.

Ubuntu is derived from Debian, and doesn't change much apart from the installer and the GUI. The `locale-gen` command is one of those few other things that it changes. I don't know why.

Under Debian, the `locale-gen` command takes no arguments and regenerates the compiled locale definitions according to the configured list of locales. To modify the selection of locales that you want to use, edit the file `/etc/locale.gen` then run the `locale-gen` command. Alternatively, run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root, select the additional locales you want (and deselect the ones you don't want), and press OK.

Under Ubuntu, if you run the `locale-gen` command without arguments, it regenerates the compiled locale definitions according to the configured list of locales. But if you pass some arguments, they're added to the list and generated immediately. The list of locales is kept in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`. Running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` just regenerates the compiled locales without giving you an opportunity to modify the selection.

In summary, to add `en_US.UTF-8` to the list of usable locales:

- Debian, interactive: `dpkg-reconfigure locales`
- Debian, automated: `sed -i 's/^# *\(en_US.UTF-8\)/\1/' /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen`
- Ubuntu, automated: `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: So how would you add packages with `dpkg-reconfigure`? I got the interactive interface, but when selecting an item with enter, it did not get installed.

Comment: @ErikDolor I don't understand your question. Unless you've changed debconf settings, `dpkg-reconfigure locales` brings up a text mode dialog box, with a checkbox for each locale that can be generated. You scroll down to `en_US.UTF-8`, check it, and press the OK button.

Comment: I tried checking it with the enter button, but that apparently functioned as pressing OK.

Comment: @ErikDolor Oh. Press Space to toggle a checkbox.

Comment: Also works for raspbian jessie

Comment: `Running dpkg-reconfigure locales just regenerates the compiled locales without giving you an opportunity to modify the selection.` this seems to have changed in ubuntu 18.04 (bionic). The behaviour is now the same as in debian.

Answer (score 8):

After actually reading the man file for locale-gen instead of blindly trusting the internet, I found that `locale-gen` actually takes the locales to generate from `/etc/locale.gen`. By uncommenting `en_US.UTF-8` there, I managed to generate it.

Comment: sed -i '/^#.* es_ES /s/^#//' /etc/locale.gen

If you are using docker this might be usefull

Comment: The ONLY answer that worked for me after scouring the internet for days!! Thank you SO MUCH!